# Modifying a value inside a loop with a function that takes ownersip of the value

Tags: rust

I would like to alter the value of a variable inside a `loop` using a function that takes ownership of the value that is to be modified and returns a new value of the same type. What I've tried thus far is something like the following:

```rust
struct Value;

fn modify (val: Value) -> Result<Value, &'static str> {
  
  // Pseudocode
  match val {
    valid => return Ok(val),
    not_valid => return Err("An error occurred")
  }
}


fn modify_until_err (val: Value) -> Value {
  
  let mut value = val;

  loop {
    let temp = match modify(value) {
      Ok(val) => val,
      Err(e) => break
    };
    value = temp;
  };

  value

}
```

With this setup I get the error

```rust
use of moved value `value`
```

I get that `modify` eats up the `value`, but if I reassign `temp` to `value`, why is the compiler still complaining?

Comment: Because in the `err` arm you've already consumed the value but you never reassign it (since you don't return it and immediately break out the loop). Incidentally you could declare `mut val` that way you wouldn't have to re-bind it. The `temp` is also unnecessary, you could just write `value = match ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is complaining because when you use `break`, you haven't assigned a new value to `value`, but you still try to return it.

There are multiple ways to get around this issue:

- Modify the `mogrify` function to return ownership of something that you would want to return from the loop
- Pass `val` by mutable reference instead of passing ownership
- Clone the value to return later

Comment: I changed to modifying function to return an `Err(unmodified_val)` if an error was encountered. That way the match arms in `modify_until_err` could have same types and I could leave the handling of the error to the calling function.